Revise code for packing books of 4 & 6 subjects together
I have a code which works for creating unique code for box packing 2 subjects book together in one box where number of books does not exceed 400. The packing must contain 2 subjects within same school and same distribution centre. It also exclude books with qty greater than 200.
Now I have to revise code for 4 subjects book & 6 subject book but the condition of packing remaining same as 400 per box and now exclude more than 100 (if 4 subjects) & exclude more than 66 (if 6 subjects).
Please help modifying the code.
    Option Explicit
    Sub GenerateUniqueCode_Stage1()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim distCenterCol As Range, schoolCol As Range, quantityCol As Range, subjectCol As Range, codeCol As Range
Dim boxCounter As Long
Dim prevDistCenter As String
Dim boxCode As String
Dim totalBooks As Long
Dim boxSubjects As String
Dim i As Long
' Set the worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
' Find the last row with data in column E
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
' Set the ranges for the columns
Set distCenterCol = ws.Range("E2:E" & lastRow)
Set schoolCol = ws.Range("G2:G" & lastRow)
Set quantityCol = ws.Range("H2:H" & lastRow)
Set subjectCol = ws.Range("I2:I" & lastRow)
Set codeCol = ws.Range("K2:K" & lastRow)
' Initialize variables
boxCounter = 1
prevDistCenter = distCenterCol.Cells(2).Value
boxCode = "BOX-" & Format(boxCounter, "000")
totalBooks = 0
boxSubjects = ""
' Loop through each row in the data
Dim j As Long, schoolBooks As Long, remainingBooks As Long
Dim distCenter As String, School As String, Subject As String
For i = 1 To lastRow - 1
    distCenter = distCenterCol.Cells(i).Value
    School = schoolCol.Cells(i).Value
    Subject = subjectCol.Cells(i).Value
    remainingBooks = quantityCol.Cells(i).Value
    schoolBooks = remainingBooks
    ' Exclude schools with quantity 100 or more
    If remainingBooks >= 100 Then
        codeCol.Cells(i).Value = "Excluded"
    Else
        For j = i + 1 To lastRow
            If prevDistCenter = distCenterCol.Cells(j).Value And _
                School = schoolCol.Cells(j).Value And _
                quantityCol.Cells(j).Value < 100 Then
                schoolBooks = schoolBooks + quantityCol.Cells(j).Value
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        ' Check if distribution center changes or adding the books exceeds the box limit
        If distCenter <> prevDistCenter Or totalBooks + schoolBooks > 300 Or _
                (InStr(1, boxSubjects, "English") = 0 And _
                InStr(1, boxSubjects, "Social & Religious Studies") = 0) Then
            ' Start a new box
            boxCounter = boxCounter + 1
            boxCode = Left(distCenter, 3) & "BOXENGSOC" & Format(boxCounter, "000")
            totalBooks = remainingBooks
            boxSubjects = Subject
        Else
            totalBooks = totalBooks + remainingBooks
            boxSubjects = boxSubjects & ", " & Subject
        End If
        ' Update the box code in column K
        codeCol.Cells(i).Value = boxCode
        ' Update the previous distribution center
        prevDistCenter = distCenter
    End If
Next i
End Sub


Sample Data



RegionNo
RegionName
DistrictNo
DistrictName
DistributionCenter
CentreNo
CentreName
Quantity
Subject
Type
UBC Code 1
Paper Type




1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
CHINTHEKWE CDSS
1148
CHINTHEKWE COMMUNITY
0
English
Type1
1ND001CHIESC1148X0001
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
CHINTHEKWE CDSS
1148
CHINTHEKWE COMMUNITY
30
Science
Type1
1ND001CHIESC1148X0001
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
CHINTHEKWE CDSS
1148
CHINTHEKWE COMMUNITY
35
MAthematics
Type1
1ND001CHIESC1148X0001
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
CHINTHEKWE CDSS
1148
CHINTHEKWE COMMUNITY
35
Biology
Type1
1ND001CHIESC1148X0001
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
CHISANSU CDSS
1254
CHISANSU COMMUNITY
0
English
Type1
1ND001CHIESC1254X0002
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
CHISANSU CDSS
1254
CHISANSU COMMUNITY
110
MAthematics
Type1
1ND001CHIESC1254X0002
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
CHISANSU CDSS
1254
CHISANSU COMMUNITY
110
Science
Type1
1ND001CHIESC1254X0002
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
CHISANSU CDSS
1254
CHISANSU COMMUNITY
110
Biology
Type1
1ND001CHIESC1254X0002
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
CHISENGA TDC
281
CHISENGA COMMUNITY
0
English
Type1
1ND001CHIESC281X0003
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
CHISENGA TDC
281
CHISENGA COMMUNITY
115
MAthematics
Type1
1ND001CHIESC281X0003
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
CHISENGA TDC
281
CHISENGA COMMUNITY
115
Science
Type1
1ND001CHIESC281X0003
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
CHISENGA TDC
281
CHISENGA COMMUNITY
115
Biology
Type1
1ND001CHIESC281X0003
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
CHISENGA TDC
1738
BRIGHT FUTURES (PVT) SECONDARY
0
English
Type1
1ND001CHIESC1738X0004
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
CHISENGA TDC
1738
BRIGHT FUTURES (PVT) SECONDARY
20
MAthematics
Type1
1ND001CHIESC1738X0004
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
CHISENGA TDC
1738
BRIGHT FUTURES (PVT) SECONDARY
20
Science
Type1
1ND001CHIESC1738X0004
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
CHISENGA TDC
1738
BRIGHT FUTURES (PVT) SECONDARY
20
Biology
Type1
1ND001CHIESC1738X0004
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
ILENGO TDC
424
KAMEME COMMUNITY
0
English
Type1
1ND001ILEESC424X0005
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
ILENGO TDC
424
KAMEME COMMUNITY
170
MAthematics
Type1
1ND001ILEESC424X0006
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
ILENGO TDC
424
KAMEME COMMUNITY
170
Science
Type1
1ND001ILEESC424X0007
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
ILENGO TDC
424
KAMEME COMMUNITY
170
Biology
Type1
1ND001ILEESC424X0007
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
KALENGE CDSS
414
KALENGE COMMUNITY
0
English
Type1
1ND001KALESC414X0008
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
KALENGE CDSS
414
KALENGE COMMUNITY
70
MAthematics
Type1
1ND001KALESC414X0008
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
KALENGE CDSS
414
KALENGE COMMUNITY
70
Science
Type1
1ND001KALESC414X0008
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
KALENGE CDSS
414
KALENGE COMMUNITY
70
Biology
Type1
1ND001KALESC414X0008
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
KALOWE TDC
851
NTHALIRE COMMUNITY
0
English
Type1
1ND001KALESC851X0009
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
KALOWE TDC
851
NTHALIRE COMMUNITY
220
MAthematics
Type1
Excluded
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
KALOWE TDC
851
NTHALIRE COMMUNITY
220
Science
Type1
Excluded
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
KALOWE TDC
851
NTHALIRE COMMUNITY
220
Biology
Type1
Excluded
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
KALOWE TDC
1515
ST IGNATIUSOF LOYOLA SECONDARY
0
English
Type1
1ND001KALESC851X0009
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
KALOWE TDC
1515
ST IGNATIUSOF LOYOLA SECONDARY
100
MAthematics
Type1
1ND001KALESC851X0009
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
KALOWE TDC
1515
ST IGNATIUSOF LOYOLA SECONDARY
100
Science
Type1
1ND001KALESC851X0009
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
KALOWE TDC
1515
ST IGNATIUSOF LOYOLA SECONDARY
100
Biology
Type1
1ND001KALESC851X0009
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
KAPILINKHONDE CDSS
441
KAPILINKHONDE COMMUNITY
0
English
Type1
1ND001KAPESC441X0010
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
KAPILINKHONDE CDSS
441
KAPILINKHONDE COMMUNITY
45
MAthematics
Type1
1ND001KAPESC441X0010
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
KAPILINKHONDE CDSS
441
KAPILINKHONDE COMMUNITY
45
Science
Type1
1ND001KAPESC441X0010
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
KAPILINKHONDE CDSS
441
KAPILINKHONDE COMMUNITY
45
Biology
Type1
1ND001KAPESC441X0010
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
KASEYE TDC
269
CHINUNKHA COMMUNITY
0
English
Type1
1ND001KASESC269X0011
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
KASEYE TDC
269
CHINUNKHA COMMUNITY
110
MAthematics
Type1
1ND001KASESC269X0011
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
KASEYE TDC
269
CHINUNKHA COMMUNITY
110
Science
Type1
1ND001KASESC269X0011
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
KASEYE TDC
269
CHINUNKHA COMMUNITY
110
Biology
Type1
1ND001KASESC269X0011
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
KASEYE TDC
1037
KASEYE GIRLS SECONDARY
0
English
Type1
1ND001KASESC1037X0012
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
KASEYE TDC
1037
KASEYE GIRLS SECONDARY
95
Science
Type1
1ND001KASESC1037X0012
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
KASEYE TDC
1037
KASEYE GIRLS SECONDARY
100
MAthematics
Type1
1ND001KASESC1037X0012
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
KASEYE TDC
1037
KASEYE GIRLS SECONDARY
100
Biology
Type1
1ND001KASESC1037X0012
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
KAWALE TDC
21
CHITIPA SECONDARY
0
English
Type1
1ND001KAWESC021X0013
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
KAWALE TDC
21
CHITIPA SECONDARY
90
Science
Type1
1ND001KAWESC021X0014
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
KAWALE TDC
21
CHITIPA SECONDARY
190
MAthematics
Type1
1ND001KAWESC021X0015
Normal


1
NORTHERN
1
CHITIPA
KAWALE TDC
21
CHITIPA SECONDARY
195
Biology
Type1
1ND001KAWESC021X0016
Normal


1
NORTHERN
2
KARONGA
IGHEMBE TDC
121
KAPORO FOUNDATION
0
English
Type1
1ND002IGHESC121X0044
Normal


1
NORTHERN
2
KARONGA
IGHEMBE TDC
121
KAPORO FOUNDATION
15
MAthematics
Type1
1ND002IGHESC121X0044
Normal


1
NORTHERN
2
KARONGA
IGHEMBE TDC
121
KAPORO FOUNDATION
15
Science
Type1
1ND002IGHESC121X0044
Normal


1
NORTHERN
2
KARONGA
IGHEMBE TDC
121
KAPORO FOUNDATION
15
Biology
Type1
1ND002IGHESC121X0044
Normal


1
NORTHERN
2
KARONGA
IGHEMBE TDC
1036
KAPORO COMMUNITY
0
English
Type1
1ND002IGHESC1036X0045
Normal


1
NORTHERN
2
KARONGA
IGHEMBE TDC
1036
KAPORO COMMUNITY
150
Science
Type1
1ND002IGHESC1036X0046
Normal


1
NORTHERN
2
KARONGA
IGHEMBE TDC
1036
KAPORO COMMUNITY
180
MAthematics
Type1
1ND002IGHESC1036X0047
Normal


1
NORTHERN
2
KARONGA
IGHEMBE TDC
1036
KAPORO COMMUNITY
180
Biology
Type1
1ND002IGHESC1036X0048
Normal



